# How to concatenate two column and one variable in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a str variable and two string columns I want to save in a new column as ID I do this

```
pos = 9
colname - df.columns[pos]
df['CNV_ID'] = str(colname) + str(df['col1']) + str(df['col2'])
```

For I reason I do not understand  this destroys the structure of my df
(cannot copy and paste df as working in a secure computer but can show screenshots.

[image]

What is going on??

If I save it and open it with a text editor, it looks even worse

[image]

(Sorry for posting pictures, I know it is not good practice but, nothing I can do)

Comment: This is quite confusing. However, if you can't provide the data as text, it significantly lowers the likelyhood that you'll get an answer.

Comment: Yeah I know. That is one of the many pain of working in a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `astype(str)`:

```
df['CNV_ID'] = colname + df['col1'].astype(str) + df['col2'].astype(str)
```